# CSS, JS folders and webpages in folders problem as per role

Tags: asp.net

I developed a web application and all my web pages were on root. here is my folder structure.

-Solution
.....js
.......xyz.js
.....css
.......abc.css
Page1.aspx
Page2.aspx
Page3.aspx
AppMaster.Master

Page4.aspx  (please note they are lying on root)
Page5.aspx  (please note they are lying on root)

I have referenced my css and js in masterpage like this.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="css/sprystylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<link href="css/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
<script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/scrollable-wizard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
<script src="js/livevalidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/qTip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.contactable.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/autoLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/autoNumeric-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now when i implemented roles to implement page access security via web.config deny users I have placed the pages like this.

-Solution
.....js
.....css
-Admin
....Page1.aspx
....Page2.aspx
-Users
....Page3.aspx
Page4.aspx
Page5.aspx

But since I've changed the folder structure I am keep getting object expected due to javascript and css is not working either. What should I do now as I am not referencing css and js specifically in every content page. Some pages will be inside specific folders and some will be on root so in this scenario how should I change the css and js location references.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a slash in front of each URL to reference them relative to the root:

```
<link href="/css/sprystylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```